# shape name changes all the time i can not find it

Tags: vba, excel, shapes, delete-operator

I have this Problem for deleting a shape in Excel with vba. Excel gives all the time different Name to These shapes, thatswhy i get error on this line:Here Activesheet is my open sheet and straight connectgor 1 is the Name of the shape, it is set as "Straight Connector 1" but when i reuse the macro it can not be found.

```
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Straight Connector 1")).Select
Selection.Delete
```

It can not find the element if i use the macro again. What should i do for this ?

Answer (score 2):

use the activtsheet.shapes collection

```
Sub connector_delete()

Dim s As Shape

For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If s.AutoShapeType = msoShapeMixed And s.Name Like "*Connector*" Then
        s.Delete
    End If
Next s


End Sub
```